# abstract out request in play controller

Tags: scala, playframework

I see repeating code like following in many methods in a play contorller. since request is available in the Actions, any way to abstract this out of all the methods to avoid repetation?

```
def serveData = Action { implicit request =>
  val host = "http://" + request.host
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
def withHost(f: String => SimpleResult) = Action { implicit request =>
  val host = "http://" + request.host
  f(host)
}

def serveData = withHost { host =>
  Ok(host)
}
```